# Regex match between two characters inclusively Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

How can I create a regex to match between two characters inclusively?

From the string  **"bar x12y bar x30y foo"** , I want to get **x12y** and **x30y**. I tried following

```
re.findall( "x(.*?)y", "bar x12y bar x30y foo")
```

and I get 12 and 30, but I would like to include x and y too, how can I do that?

Comment: This is a [139th duplicate already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/31915018?lq=1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no it is not, they are different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include the `x` and `y` in the capture group. Since your pattern defines only a single group you can leave out the parentheses altogether:

```py
re.findall("x.*?y", "bar x12y bar x30y foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use non capturing groups to achieve your purpose

```
re.findall(r'x(?:.*?)y', "bar x12y bar x30y foo")
```

a better regular expression would be

regex: `\bx\d+y\b`